# Multiple HTTP request using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to js and ajax.
I want a code that calls a `disp.php` file and display its output in `load.php`. The ajax code should pass a value from `load.php` to `disp.php` and there must be a five second delay between each call.

Basically I want to replace the below php code which will fail due to script timeout. `load()` and `disp()` are functions of `disp.php`

```
require("disp.php");

for($i = 1; $i <= $pt[1]; $i++)
{
    load($mat,$i);
    disp();
    sleep(5);     
}
```

Comment: Where is Ajax coming into picture here? This is completely PHP.

Comment: I want to replace the above 'for' loop with ajax,ie, to call the php script one by one to prevent timeout

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an Ajax call from Javascript see this [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

And to make the call after every five seconds use setTimeout

```
<script>
   function callLoad() {
       ......write logic to call the PHP file here... 
   } 

   var callCount = 0;

   function callLoop() {
       callLoad();
       callCount ++;

       if(callCount == 5) return; // Stop the loop

       setTimeout(function() {
           callLoop();
      }, 5000); // Wait for 5 second to make the call again

   } 

   window.onload = callLoop; // Start the loop after the page has finished loading
</script>
```